# Unexpected Data Usage in React Native App - Frequent Requests to kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: react-native, expo

I've developed a React Native application using the Expo/EAS framework. Recently, one of my iOS users reported that the app is consuming an unusually large amount of data (~10GB per day) even when the app is idle or not actively used. From my end, I've been able to verify and account for less than 100MB of this daily data consumption.

To help diagnose the issue, I requested the user to monitor the network traffic on their device using "My Data Manager" app. Interestingly, they observed consistent requests being made to kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com approximately every minute. Each of these requests is averaging about 6.6MB.

This behavior is unexpected, and I haven't explicitly set up any such requests in my codebase.

Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Review your NPM or other scripts you use from third parties. Some of them are Malware and pretend to be a useful package

Comment: Thanks @FistonEmmanuel - I have already been through all the packages and I can't see anything that rings any alarm-bells.  On closer inspection however it seems this may be coming from "react-native-adapty" - I'll get in touch with Adapty to see if they can assist.